# Doctrine 2.1 and tables utf-8 coding

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm

Could someone tell me how to force Doctrine to create database tables with UTF-8 coding and `utf8_polish_ci`? My Doctrine config file has this db configuration parameters:

```
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '*****',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array(1002=>'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

Nevertheless, it's still creating table with default coding: `latin1` and `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Comment: Why are you using doctrine to *create* tables in the first place? Would that not be something you do in whichever database administration tool you use?

Comment: @Pekka - letting Doctrine2 manage your DDL statements for you is the preferred way to do things in Doctrine2.  orm:schema-tool:[create|update] being the relevant commands for the command-line tooling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You set it in your database, doctrine just uses the databases default values. See this question from the [Doctrine 2.1 FAQ:](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/faq.html)

> **4.1.1. How do I set the charset and collation for MySQL tables?**
>
> You can’t set these values inside the annotations, yml or xml mapping files. To make a database work with the default charset and collation you should configure MySQL to use it as default charset, or create the database with charset and collation details. This way they get inherited to all newly created database tables and columns.

Comment: Where I can set those default values of my DB?

Answer (score 4):

Use code below to set Doctrine collation, charset and engine:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="temporary", options={"collate"="utf16_latin_ci", "charset"="utf16", "engine"="MyISAM"})  
* @ORM\Entity
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create your database, you should create it like this:

`` CREATE DATABASE `your_table_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci; ``

that will allow your created tables to inherit the charset and collate values